# jQuery draggable function and while loops

Tags: php, jquery

I've created a simple while loop that produces random images I have in my folder. I want to be able to drag these images anywhere on my webpage. I used the draggable function for jQuery but it does not work. My question is does this even work? Here is the code simplified.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function() 
        {
            $("#draggable").draggable();
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
$num_dresses = dress_count ();

$i = 0;

while ($i < 5)
{   
    $rand_id = rand(1, $num_dresses);
    $dress_feed_data = clothing_data($rand_id, 'file_name');    
    $new_file_name = html_entity_decode($dress_feed_data['file_name']); 

    if (file_exists('fashion_images/' . $new_file_name))
    {
?>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
<img src=" fashion_images/<?php echo $new_file_name;?> " width="70" height="70"/>
</div>

<?php } 
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Here is the code viewed as the page source. I cut out anything that wasn't related to the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(function() 
            {
                $(".ui-widget-content").draggable();
            });
        });
        </script>
        <style>
            #draggable { width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 0.5em; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
            <img src=" fashion_images/blouse_belk's_0 " width="70" height="70"/>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
            <img src=" fashion_images/red|nail|polish_opi_0 " width="70" height="70"/>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
            <img src=" fashion_images/brown|pants_community|store_0 " width="70" height="70"/>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
            <img src=" fashion_images/jeans_larry_0 " width="70" height="70"/>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
            <img src=" fashion_images/pepsi|tshirt_target_1 " width="70" height="70"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typically it not the best idea to have several elements on the page with the same id

try doing something like this maybe it helps

```
<div class="ui-widget-content">
```

and get the element by class

```
$(".ui-widget-content").draggable();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. I changed the selector to .ui-widget-content but it still does not work.

Comment: @jason328 can you show the codebehind from view source that actually generated

Comment: Sure thing. Added it to my question.

Comment: @ jason328      here is a jfidle http://jsfiddle.net/3YkHn/ with a working example as you can see I did not modified anything I would suggest make sure you reference jquery and jqueryui

Answer (score 1):

Your source code is not including the jquery plugin. Try to put this before de `</head>` tag

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's in there. I just took it out to simplify the problem.

Comment: Is the jquery ui plugin to? Try to paste the complete source code.

Comment: I forgot the jQuery UI. This is my first working with UI. Sorry about that. It works now.

Comment: Great, try using firebug on Mozilla or Google Chrome so you can see the javascript error on console! =)

Answer (score 0):

You should include [jquery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js) and [jquery ui](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js).

A [code](http://jsfiddle.net/zxBDR/3/) similar to yours works for me

Answer (score 0):

Here i have done complete bins for above issue.

**DEMO** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9u

To solve above draggable problem, you have to first include latest jquery.js and jquery-ui.js (jquery plugin) java script files in header and apply draggable function on all selectors (elements) which has same class say "ui-widget-content" because we should not set same id on more than one element if this will happen then jQuery couldn't work because it will not identify correct element and apply function on only first element.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui-widget-content">
  <img src="http://www3.pictures.fp.zimbio.com/Paris+Fashion+Week+Chanel+Spring+Summer+2009+0IojzkQwqGlt.jpg" width="70" height="70"/>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content">
  <img src="http://www.fashion-doll-guide.com/images/2010-hallmark-barbie-christmas-ornaments-3.jpg" width="70" height="70"/>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content">
  <img src="http://www.fashion-doll-guide.com/images/Holiday-Barbie-Dolls.jpg" width="70" height="70"/>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content">
  <img src="http://www1.pictures.stylebistro.com/gi/KW+Kanye+West+Runway+Paris+Fashion+Week+Spring+rq5fOR7SZfjt.jpg" width="70" height="70"/>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content">
  <img src="http://www.theuniuni.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/70x70/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/a/fashion-waterproof-platform-mature-horse-fur-01.jpg" width="70" height="70"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-widget-content{
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:move;
}
.ui-widget-content img{
  border:1px solid #112266;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".ui-widget-content").draggable();
});
```